# Parsing ATCO CIF files to produce a CSV or XML output

Tags: sqlite, parsing, csv

I have a bunch of .cif files, totaling around 33Mb that hold information about local busses and their timetables. Each line starts with a different identifier to indicate what the line is all about.

Example line:

`QSN319 020S3_20110104219912311111100  S3        LFBUS           O`

Indicates that this is a bus journey information, some various dates and the days of the week the bus `S3` runs on. You can have a look at a more detailed example http://pastebin.com/3jzp6QL9

What i need to do is somehow parse all (or partially selected, for example I won't need `QSN` part in my database) data into a CSV or XML for further SQLite import. I just need a push in the right direction and some tools that i can use. Would awk and sed be enough to do this or shall I look more into writing a parser from scratch.

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had pretty good success with David J. Rice's [ATCO-CIF parser](https://github.com/davidjrice/atco). It's written in Ruby.